# How to "do something" if 3 buttons clicked ? (I tried with this : )

Tags: javascript

Im having troubles with one part of my code.
Yesterday, I tried it and it was fully working, and now it is not working anymore.
I really don't understand so if you guys see something, tell me !

```
var FERNC1 = document.getElementById('pc1');
var FERNC2 = document.getElementById('pc11');
var UNNC1 = document.getElementById('pc8');

FERNC1.addEventListener('click', function () {
    fer1 = 1;
    bronze1 = 0;
    argent1 = 0;
    or1 = 0;
    platine1 = 0;
    diamant1 = 0;
    immortel1 = 0;
    console.log(fer1);
    FERNC2.addEventListener('click', function () {
        fer2 = 1;
        bronze2 = 0;
        argent2 = 0;
        or2 = 0;
        platine2 = 0;
        diamant2 = 0;
        immortel2 = 0;
        console.log(fer2);
        UNNC1.addEventListener('click', function () {
            un1 = 1;
            deux1 = 0;
            trois1 = 0;
            console.log(un1);

            if ((fer1 == 1 && fer2 == 1 && un1 == 1)) {
                document.getElementById('pc88').classList.add('inactiveLink');
                document.getElementById("s7").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("s8").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("s9").style.display = "none";
            }
            else {
                document.getElementById('pc88').classList.remove('inactiveLink');
                document.getElementById("s7").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("s8").style.display = "none";
                document.getElementById("s9").style.display = "none";
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Thank you guys

Comment: Can you please tell us what do you actually mean by "3 buttons clicked"? Do you want to click 3 different buttons at the same time?

Comment: Saying "it was working, but it doesn't work now" gives no information to help understanding your question. Read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: To explain : I was thinking about setting the variables on 1 when they're clicked, and if all of them (3) are clicked, do "that". And yeah, my question is dumb, like, it's not buttons but 3 square which are "selectionnable" while changing color when you click on it. And I want that if you click on 3 of them, we can do something (like I did in the "if" part).

Comment: That being said, just by looking at your code, adding event listener within an event listener within an event listener is almost certainly a bad idea.

Comment: Yes I know, but I don't know how to do it. I tried things, and now im here if you have a better idea :/

Comment: By "it's not buttons but 3 square which are "selectionnable" while changing color when you click on it." do you mean checkboxes?

Answer (score 1):

The bets must be checked each time the buttons are clicked, like below:

```
FERNC1.addEventListener('click', function () {
fer1 = 1;
bronze1 = 0;
argent1 = 0;
or1 = 0;
platine1 = 0;
diamant1 = 0;
immortel1 = 0;
console.log(fer1);
if ((fer1 == 1 && fer2 == 1 && un1 == 1)) {
            document.getElementById('pc88').classList.add('inactiveLink');
            document.getElementById("s7").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("s8").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("s9").style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('pc88').classList.remove('inactiveLink');
            document.getElementById("s7").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("s8").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("s9").style.display = "none";
        }
}
FERNC2.addEventListener('click', function () {
    fer2 = 1;
    bronze2 = 0;
    argent2 = 0;
    or2 = 0;
    platine2 = 0;
    diamant2 = 0;
    immortel2 = 0;
    console.log(fer2);
    if ((fer1 == 1 && fer2 == 1 && un1 == 1)) {
        document.getElementById('pc88').classList.add('inactiveLink');
        document.getElementById("s7").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("s8").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("s9").style.display = "none";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById('pc88').classList.remove('inactiveLink');
        document.getElementById("s7").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("s8").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("s9").style.display = "none";
    }
  }
UNNC1.addEventListener('click', function () {
        un1 = 1;
        deux1 = 0;
        trois1 = 0;
        console.log(un1);

        if ((fer1 == 1 && fer2 == 1 && un1 == 1)) {
            document.getElementById('pc88').classList.add('inactiveLink');
            document.getElementById("s7").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("s8").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("s9").style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('pc88').classList.remove('inactiveLink');
            document.getElementById("s7").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("s8").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("s9").style.display = "none";
        }
    });
```

Comment: Oh yeah it's working right now ! Thank y'all.  PS : don't forget the ")" after the "}" just before the eventlisteners :)

Answer (score 0):

**Requirement**:

- There are 3 buttons
- When all three buttons are clicked (in any order, and any number of times greater than 1), some particular block-of-code needs to be executed.

**Approach**:

```
const clickCounter = { btn1: 0, btn2: 0, btn3: 0 };
const areOtherBtnsClicked = (btn = 'btn1') => ( 
  Object.entries(clickCounter).reduce(
    (f, ([k, v])) => (k === btn ? f : f && v > 0),
    true
  )
);
const btnClickHandler = (btnNumber = 'btn1') => {
  clickCounter[btnNumber]++;
  if (areOtherBtnsClicked(btnNumber)) {
    someCodeBlock;
  }
};
```

Then, within the relevant part of the script, the `btnClickHandler` may be listed as the click-handler for each button by passing the button-number as an argument. So, something like this: `addEventListener('click', ('<<bt1 or btn2 or btn3 goes here>>') => btnClickHandler())`.

Some syntax errors may be present in above. Please comment or edit as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just add a class to your elements ?

Then it would be :

```
var clickableElement = document.querySelector('.customClass');

clickableElement.addEventListener('click', function () {

    if (this.id == "pc1") {

        fer1 = 1;
        bronze1 = 0;
        argent1 = 0;
        or1 = 0;
        platine1 = 0;
        diamant1 = 0;
        immortel1 = 0;
        console.log(fer1);

    } else if (this.id == "pc11") {

        fer2 = 1;
        bronze2 = 0;
        argent2 = 0;
        or2 = 0;
        platine2 = 0;
        diamant2 = 0;
        immortel2 = 0;
        console.log(fer2);

    } else if (this.id == "pc8") {

        un1 = 1;
        deux1 = 0;
        trois1 = 0;
        console.log(un1);

        if ((fer1 == 1 && fer2 == 1 && un1 == 1)) {
            document.getElementById('pc88').classList.add('inactiveLink');
            document.getElementById("s7").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("s8").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("s9").style.display = "none";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('pc88').classList.remove('inactiveLink');
            document.getElementById("s7").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("s8").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("s9").style.display = "none";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your return, I think this might be a good idea!
I just need to add the same class to every element ?

Comment: I'm glad if I can help. Yes, every element you want to link to these particular actions need to have the same class. Then you put their ids in conditional tags as I did, and do the particular action you need. Don't hesitate to mark this answer as validate once you tried it, if it indeed worked as you expected.

Comment: Thank you, and yeah of course. Im trying it, but it's not working actually,. Even in the logs, it's not showing me the variables = 1 ect..
I applied the same class on every element, but do i have to create this class in the CSS even if im not using it ? Or can it be only an 'imaginary' class on the HTML to link elements ? Thx

Comment: You have to write the class inside the elements of your HTML file of course. Could you create a https://codepen.io/pen/ with your HTML and your JS ? CSS is not required.

Comment: I found the solution man. Thanks a lot for your help. Have a great day.

Comment: Ok glad you found the solution. Have a great day.